# Making wget rename existing filenames sanely

Tags: filenames, wget

When filename already exists using `wget`, it renames the file to `filename.extension.1`. Is it possible to make it rename it to `filename.1.extension` -- which should have been the default?

Answer (score 4):

No.

`wget` adds a backup suffix to the existing filename without trying to interpret, parse or otherwise make sense of the filename.  This is also consistent with the default behaviour of other utilities that creates backups of files.

The editors `vim`, `emacs` and `nano` (and probably most others) can be configured to add a backup suffix to filenames (by default `~` in these three).  The `sed` stream editor can do in-place editing and at the same time back up the original using `sed -i.suffix` (would add `.suffix` to the end of the filename).  The GNU `mv` and `cp` utilities can make backups with varying degree of sophistication, but always appending a suffix to the end of the filename. `rsync`, likewise, can add a suffix to files before replacing the original with an updated file.  etc.

Adding a backup number in the middle of a filename is problematic, not least because filenames can be any string not containing `/`.  For example, where would the backup number be placed in `file.tar.gz` or `myfile.7` if not at the end?

Answer (score 2):

Although, once downloaded you could just

```
perl-rename -i "s/(.*)(\.extension)(\.[0-9]+)$/\1\3\2/" *
```

for whichever version of `rename` you have available.

With `perl-rename`, Use the `-i` option to avoid over-writing existing files. Use `-n` to do a 'dry run'.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to share my solution:

`alias wget='func(){ (wget --tries=0 --retry-connrefused --timeout=30 -O download_pkg.tmp "$1" && mv download_pkg.tmp "${1##*/}") || rm download_pkg.tmp;  unset -f func; }; func`

it creates a function that receives a parameter "url" to download the file to a temporary name. If it is successful, it is renamed to the correct filename extracted from parameter $1 with ${1##*/}. and if it fails, deletes the temp file. If the operation is aborted, the temp file will be replace on the next run. after all, unset -f removes the function definition as the alias is executed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. It would appear that you have accidentally created two accounts.  This will interfere with commenting and editing your own posts.  You should use the [contact form](/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles” to have your accounts merged.  In order to merge them, you will need to provide links to the two accounts.  For your information, they are https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/548612/joaoptc and https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/548613/joaoptc.